# Construct matrix using selection of rows and columns in numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix

In `NumPy`, suppose I have a matrix `X`:

```
X = array([[3, 1, 4, 5], [5, 1, 2, 1], [4, 4, 0, 1], [0, 3, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

How can I construct a new matrix using the first (row 0), last second and last (row 3, 4) of `X`?

The resulting matrix is:

```
Y = array([[3, 1, 4, 5], [0, 3, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I cannot list all the rows I want to include for the new matrix because for the data I have, it will be like choosing the (20, 60), (90, 120) row of the original matrix to construct a new matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to get those concatenated row indices and simply index into the rows of the input array, like so -

```
X[np.r_[0, 3:5]]        # for sample case

X[np.r_[20:60, 90:120]] # for actual case
```

Sample run -

```
In [146]: X
Out[146]: 
array([[3, 1, 4, 5],
       [5, 1, 2, 1],
       [4, 4, 0, 1],
       [0, 3, 0, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [147]: X[np.r_[0, 3:5]]
Out[147]: 
array([[3, 1, 4, 5],
       [0, 3, 0, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Sample run for shape test on a bigger random array -

```
In [150]: X = np.random.rand(200,10)

In [151]: X[np.r_[20:60, 90:120]].shape
Out[151]: (70, 10) # 70 rows selected
```